# RABL renders ActiveRecord timestamps or datetimes as numbers instead of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, sinatra, rabl

I'm currently in the process of switching from ActiveRecord's `as_json` to RABL for API generation.

`as_json` has been rendering timestamps in my models as strings of the format `2012-09-16T22:14:11+00:00`. However, when I switched to RABL timestamps started rendering as epoch numbers like `1347926218.084763000` (note these dates are from two different objects and are not supposed to be equal). Is there a way to force the string format?

My .rabl template is pretty simple:

```
object @person
attributes :id, :created_on, :name
```

and I get:

```
{"id":3,"created_on":1347926218.084763000,"name":"fred"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 object @person
   node(:id){|person|(person.id)}
   node(:created_on){|person|(person.created_on.strftime(%d,%m,%Y)}
   node(:name){|person|(person.name)}
 end
```

or try

```
 object @person
   attributes :id, :name
   node(:created_on){|person|(person.created_on.strftime(%d,%m,%Y)}
 end
```

There are more options for .strftime() you can find on many sites.  It must be used on a :date object type.  You can customize the date output with it's options.  I'm working on custom nodes for some json output and am learning this the hard way!

If you need the the attributes in a certain order I'd use the one with nodes because the attributes seem to 'float to the top' of the json object created.

Comment: Ah, this is cool. I wish it worked out of the box, but this seems like a good replacement. Thanks!